# How do i disable aspectRatio in Jcrop

Tags: php, javascript, jcrop

i'm actually working with Jcrop (http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/10/17/jquery-image-cropper-with-uploader/).

I want to put a ratio of 2:3

**or**

to disable competly the 'aspectRatio' and make the user free to crop what he want.

I just finish to read the documentation, but i'm not really got in english so I didn't find the answer i was looking for, can some here can help me to do this?

Thanks to everybody.

Comment: Could you post the code you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done ! 
**aspectRatio : 1 --------- became 5 / 3 :)**

```
$(this).fadeIn().Jcrop({
        onChange: showPreview,
        onSelect: showPreview,
        aspectRatio: 5 / 3,
        onSelect: updateCoords,
        setSelect: [ 0, 0, 150, 150 ]
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find it documented anywhere either, but looking at the source code, setting the aspect ratio to zero via the api will disable it.

Also not putting it on in the first place will leave it at the default zero.